# Removing Installed Windows Hotfixes

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to write a small script to remove all installed Hotfixes on a Win 10 Machine. Since I didn't find a module capable of this, I've used `Start-Process wusa.exe -ArgumentList`

While the text file does indeed only contain pure numbers needed for the variable in the ArgumentList (otherwise it would be KBKB1234565), nothing happens.

I'm not sure how to see what wusa actually does, so i'm stuck with something that doesn't work, but i don't know why.

Powershell 5.1.16299.98, ExecutionPolicy unsigned, elevated shell on a local AdminAccount.

```
#get ONLY the KB number and write in file
$KB = Get-Hotfix | Select HotfixID 
$KB -replace ".*B" -replace "}" | Out-File c:\temp\temp.txt -append
$KB = Get-Content "C:\temp\temp.txt"

#remove all KBs in said file
ForEach ($Hotfix in $KB)
{
    Write-Host "Uninstalling KB$Hotfix"
    Start-Process wusa.exe -ArgumentList "/uninstall /KB:$Hotfix /quiet /norestart" -Wait 
}
```

Edit: EventViewer sais (translated) this:

```
Due to an error, the Windows-Update could not be uninstalled. 
Error: 2147942487 "Wrong Parameter." 
(CommandLine:""C:\WINDOWS\system32\wusa.exe" /uninstall /KB:4054517 /quiet /norestart ")
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Uninstalling OS updates is usually not a great idea.

Comment: I have some weird issues with some PCs where they hang at random tasks, so i figured i uninstall all updates and reinstall them manually one by one. I know i can achieve the same thing the other way around, but i'm guessing the Start-Process -ArgumentList part will come up in one way or another again.

Comment: Even though PS is elevated, it's possible that `wusa` is being started as a non-elevated process because you're using `Start-Process`. Try adding `-Verb runAs` to `Start-Process` as this will elevate it.

Comment: without `/quiet` it works but requires a user interaction. That's okay with me for now. RunAs unfortunately doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one-liner that does the same thing.

```
(get-hotfix).hotfixid.replace("KB","") | % {& wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:$_ /quiet /norestart}
```

As far as your issue, you are doing it right. From some quick googling, it's possible that you have a corrupt hotfix, but unlikely. What's interesting is that when I try to uninstall one with a bogus KB code, it gives me a different error code.

For the error, try uninstalling just the specific hotfix that throws the error, and report back what the event logs say/what `WUSA` says.

i.e. (without quiet, so you can see what it says)

`wusa.exe /uninstall /KB:4054517 /norestart`